# How do I change properties of an SVG linked as object when hovering over its parent div?

Tags: javascript, css, xml, svg, raphael

Okay, this is the scenario:

> *Wrapper DIV > Icon DIV > SVG* using Object tag and text

Now, my requirement is that we you hover over the *wrapper DIV*, the color of the SVG (Class:`iconSVG`) should change, which apparently doesn't work. What I did was this:

```
.wrapperDiv:hover .iconDiv .iconSVG .st0 {
   fill:#ffffff;
}
```

(`.st0` is the class created by *Illustrator* for say, a particular shape inside `iconSVG`)

This didn't do what I intended it to, but when I replace the object with an inline SVG, the above hover works perfect. Now, I really would love to keep SVG files separate from the main HTML. Is there a way to do this or am I stuck with inline SVG? I read in many articles that when SVG is called using an object tag inside HTML would give us control over their CSS properties, so I tried it.

Sorry if I am missing the obvious - I am a designer basically and new to this programming stuff (I am taking baby steps here).

Should I learn Javascript to accomplish this? (I hear *RaphaelJS* gives great opportunities for creating impressive stuff with SVG). Though this might be a separate thread, I'd like to know if spending time to learn RaphaelJS would be worth for a UI/UX Developer (I have basic knowledge of JS, but is that enough?)

Comment: If you want to affect the SVG with raw CSS it should be inline HTML element. However, there is this - http://css-tricks.com/svg-use-external-source/

Answer (score 2):

You can't change any styles of SVG elements you load as an `<img>`, but you *do* have some limited possibilities if you load the SVG as an `<object>`.

Assuming you load your SVG like this:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <object type="image/svg+xml" data="your-svg.svg" class="wrapper"></object>
    </body>
</html>
```

And your SVG contains this code:

```
<svg id="my-svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="300px" height="300px">
    <g class="svg-icon" alignment-baseline="baseline">
        <circle r="50" cx="100" cy="100" stroke="blue" fill="green" opacity=".5"/>
        <rect class="st0" x="100" y="100" height="100" width="100" stroke="red" opacity=".5"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

you can add a `<style>` block inside it with your CSS:

```
<svg id="my-svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="300px" height="300px">
    <style type="text/css">
        .svg-icon:hover .st0 {
           fill:#ffffff;
        }
    </style>
    <g class="svg-icon" alignment-baseline="baseline">...</g>
</svg>
```

and it will change the fill color of the square when you hover it (and will not change the color of the circle). This won't work with a CSS file loaded by the browser (using HTML `<link>`), but should work if you load a stylesheet in the *standard XML way*, using the [xml-stylesheet processing instruction](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-stylesheet/) before your `<svg>...</svg>` root element:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="svgstyle.css" ?>

<svg id="my-svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="300px" height="300px">
    <g class="svg-icon" alignment-baseline="baseline">
        <circle r="50" cx="100" cy="100" stroke="blue" fill="green" opacity=".5"/>
        <rect class="st0" x="100" y="100" height="100" width="100" stroke="red" opacity=".5"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

With that you can share CSS documents between your SVG and HTML, but you should be aware that the *scope* of the contextual selectors is limited to each file (e.g. you can't have CSS expressions mixing selectors from HTML and SVG, like `div:hover .svg-icon {...}`)

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. I shall try that and update you.